# Corrupted ibdata1 and can't run server

Tags: mysql, corruption

I am running a local dev environment on OSX. I restarted the machine earlier, and since then, I cannot load mysql server.

I am running mysql 8.0.23

I get the following message when I try to load `mysqld`:

```
2021-06-19T20:19:33.571664Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.23_1/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 28852
2021-06-19T20:19:33.572870Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-06-19T20:19:33.577870Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-19T20:19:33.674090Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012224] [InnoDB] Tablespace flags are invalid in datafile: ./ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 21. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-19T20:19:33.674204Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012237] [InnoDB] Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile './ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2021-06-19T20:19:33.674258Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption.
2021-06-19T20:19:33.674733Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2021-06-19T20:19:33.674936Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-06-19T20:19:33.675039Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-19T20:19:33.675341Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.23_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  Homebrew.
```

I am unable to load the server in either safe mode or by using innodb_force_recovery 0-6.

When I try to run innodb_force_recovery > 0, I get a different issue:

```
2021-06-19T20:24:18.342561Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.23_1/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 29779
2021-06-19T20:24:18.344846Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350490Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350528Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350595Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012936] [InnoDB] Database upgrade cannot be accomplished with innodb_force_recovery > 0
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350624Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350658Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350779Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-06-19T20:24:18.350837Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-19T20:24:18.351053Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.23_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  Homebrew.
```

Is my data gone?

Comment: try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Comment: The `Database upgrade cannot be accomplished with innodb_force_recovery > 0` is usually a pretty bad sign. I hope you make regular backups … 

Comment: Sounds like it's a dead end if innodb_force_recovery doesn't work. Had to clear out data, re-initialize and restore (older than I would have liked) backup.